# how to Hide list default in input html?

Tags: html

How do I remove the default list of input
see in images:

[image]

html INPUT TEXT remove browser default dropdown

```
<input name="serch" type="text" />
```

Comment: autocomplete="off" :p

Answer (score 1):

That's coming from the browser cache. If the browser is compliant, `autocomplete="off"` should work:

```
<input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `autocomplete="off` as an attribute and value for the relevant `input` element, in order to prevent the suggestions from being presented.